# Why is it so in python?

Tags: python

I'm swamped with this logic:

```
n1=10
n2=3
n3=7
n1 = float(("1st"))
n2 = float(("2nd"))
n3 = float(("3rd"))
if n1>=n2 and n1>=n3:
   h=n1 
elif n2>=n1 and n2>=n3:
   h=n2
else:
   h=n3
print(h)
```

I garner up with input as follows:

```
 n1 54.0
 n2 3
 n3 7
```

It compiled fine, but shows strange output:

```
 1st54
 2nd
```

It don't even taking input for 2nd number, rather it shows "program terminated".

Pls run it on your pc for better understanding.

Comment: How does `float(("1st"))` run? I don't see how this can compile. Indeed, in the python 3.5.2 shell it failed.

Comment: It's takin' an input like integer does.

Comment: you cannot float a string. "1st" is un-parsable string.

Comment: @AnshSrivastava No, like @Daniel alluded, `float(("1st"))` will throw a `ValueError` because "1st" cannot be converted to a float. This will work only if you have defined a separate function `float(...)` to shadow the builtin `float`.

Comment: Did you mean to use 'float(input("1st"))?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant to have `float(input("1st"))`, your code seems to work for me in python 3.7.0. Try running this code:

```
n1 = float(input("1st"))
n2 = float(input("2nd"))
n3 = float(input("3rd"))
if n1>=n2 and n1>=n3:
   h=n1 
elif n2>=n1 and n2>=n3:
   h=n2
else:
   h=n3
print(h)
```

Entering 54.0, 3 and 7 as input gives 54.0 as output. Here's a picture:

[image]